# UWP Xaml Page scale after migrating from Win 8.1

Tags: xaml, uwp, scale, dpi

im currently working on tablet app migration from Win 8.1 to UWP. I created a new blank UWP and added all xaml pages and c# code to it. App is now running without any errors or crashes but i have problems with page layouts. In Win 8.1 every controller was scaled to fit the screen size. Now in Win10 UWP project, if i compare the win 8.1 and UWP app fonts and controllers are almost twice as big as they were on win 8.1 ... Is there something i forgot to do during the migration process ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable DPI scaling

```
bool result = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewScaling.TrySetDisableLayoutScaling(true);
```

Or set to 100% DPI in display properties

Comment: disabling DPI scaling didnt change anything. Where can i find display properties ?

Comment: in windows settings win+i